# how to compare (strcmp) 2 char with space?

Tags: c++, arrays, string, char, strcmp

```cpp
#include <iostream>
#include <cstring>
#include <cctype>     

using namespace std;

int main(){
    char string1 [50] {};
    char string2 [50] {};
    
    cout << "enter the string 1: ";
    cin.get(string1,50);
    cout << "your string1: " << string1 << endl;
    
    
    cout << "enter the string 2: ";
    cin.get(string2,50);
    cout << "your string2: " << string2 << endl;
    
    cout << strcmp(string1, string2);

    return 0;
}
```

How to use `strcmp()` wit `string1` (with space) and `string2` (with space)?

What I've tried:

Input:

```
abc def
```

Output:

```
your string1: abc def
enter the string 2: your string2:
1
```

The result that I want:

Input:

```
abc def
abc def
```

Output:

```
0
```

Comment: What exactly is your question? Everything seems to be working as expected, strcmp returns 0 if the strings are the same.

Comment: `strcmp` doesn't give a crap about spaces, so the problem is elsewhere. You should check the documentation for [`std::istream::get`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_istream/get) to ensure it behaves the way you are expecting. For example, does it remove the end of line character from the stream?

Comment: If you're using C+, **use C++** and embrace `std::string`. C strings are covered in thorns.

Comment: The first `get` stops at the newline. The second `get` only sees the newline so it reads nothing. You need a `cin.ignore()` after the first read to consume it. You could use `cin.getline` instead. https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_istream/get The important part: "the next available input character c equals delim, as determined by Traits::eq(c, delim). This character is not extracted (unlike basic_istream::getline())"

Comment: @RetiredNinja that should be posted as an answer instead.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's the issue:

`cin.get(string1,50);` reads up to 49 characters or until it encounters a `\n` but it doesn't consume the `\n`.

When `cin.get(string2,50);` is reached the `\n` from the first line is the first character in the input buffer so nothing is read.

There's a few ways I can think of to fix this.

1. Keep using [cin.get](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_istream/get) and add a [cin.ignore()](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_istream/ignore) after the first read to consume the `\n`. If more than 49 characters were entered on a line the `ignore` would cause the 50th character to be lost.
2. Switch to using [cin.getline](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_istream/getline) with the same parameters. The difference is that `cin.getline` does consume the `\n`. If more than 49 characters were entered on a line this wouldn't lose any characters, it would read from 50 to 99 or until a `\n` was reached.

There are some other small differences with error handling that don't affect your code as written but you might review the linked documentation for each to decide which is best.

3. If you are able to I strongly encourage using [std::string](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string) for your variables and [std::getline](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/getline) to read the data. The advantage to this is that you don't need to worry about specifying an explicit length. The amount of data that is provided will be read and the string resized to fit it. This would help to close the loophole where more than 49 characters were supplied on a line.

Here's an example using `cin.getline` that gives the output you expect.

[Demo](https://godbolt.org/z/WzKE1Woez)

Output:

```
enter the string 1: 
your string1: 'abc def'
enter the string 2: 
your string2: 'abc def'
0
```

It's slightly different from your original code since I added single quotes around the string and a couple of newlines to make it a little more readable and help to validate what was going on.